# Split a dynamic div into two columns using jquery and CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div which may contain a huge amount of text content. I have to split it into a two column view. ([Example](http://www.scribd.com/read/163578875/Final-Appeal)).

Is there any way to split HTML content using jquery?

Comment: This plugin is nice and does the job. http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 3):

```css
 .col {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
  -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid #ccc;

  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 40px;
  -moz-column-rule: 1px solid #ccc;

  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 40px;
  column-rule: 1px solid #ccc;
 }

 .col h1,  .col h2, .col h3, .col h4, .col h5, .col h6 {
  -webkit-column-span:all;
  -moz-column-span:all;
  column-span:all;
 }
```

```html
<div class='col'>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css columns:

```css
div {
        -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
         column-count: 2;
        
        -webkit-column-gap: 20px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-gap: 20px; /* Firefox */
         column-gap: 20px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.
</div>
```

Current Browser Support:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn